# Integrate separate year, month, day, hour, minute and second columns as a single timestamp column

Tags: postgresql, types, timestamp

My data set contains separate year, month, day, hour, minute, and second columns as following that are separated by space:

```
+-------------------+
|2007|09|28|21|14|06|
|2007|09|28|21|14|06|
|2007|09|28|21|14|06|
|2007|09|28|21|14|06|
|2007|09|28|21|14|06|
+-------------------+
```

I wanted to integrate them as a single column under timestamp data-type.
I have created a new column in timestamp data-type and update the column by following code:

```
 Update s2
 set dt = year || '-' || month  || '-' || day
               || ' ' || hour  || ':' || min  || ':' || second
```

But I faced by following error:

```
ERROR:  column "dt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
LINE 1:  Update temp set dt= year || '-' || month  || '-' || day  ||...
                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "dt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 22
```

Moreover, I can preform the integration by `varchar` data-type.

Comment: `column "dt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text, You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.` That seems like good advice. Did you try that?

Comment: @Mat, yes I have tried it and defined the year, month, day as date data-type and hour, minute, and second as time data-type then I did the command but aforementioned error was observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the expression

```
year || '-' || month  || '-' || day || ' ' || hour  || ':' || min  || ':' || second
```

is not a timestamp but a plain text. The error message simply tells you, that the type `text` is not appropriate to the type of the `dt` column.

You must cast the *complete* expression like this:

```
(year || '-' || month  || '-' || day || ' ' || hour  || ':' || min  || ':' || second)::timestamp
```

Answer (score 5):

You got answers explaining the error: You need to cast the `text` to `timestamp` explicitly.

However, the proper solution is to use [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE)

```
UPDATE s2
SET dt = to_timestamp(year || '-' || month  || '-' || day || ' '
                           || hour  || ':' || min  || ':' || second
                     ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss');
```

Why?
The plain cast `'text'::timestamp` depends on local settings for date / time format and may work in one installation but "suddenly" fail in another installation of PostgreSQL. The given statement is guaranteed to work, independent of [`datestyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) settings and locale.

Well, to be precise, the pattern in the example (`'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'`) matches ISO 8601 (SQL standard), which is valid for *any* locale.

Answer (score 2):

You need simple cast from `text` to `timestamp without time zone`:

```
(expression)::timestamp without time zone
```

For example:

```
Update s2 set dt = (year || '-' || month  || '-' || day  || ' ' || hour  || ':' || min  || ':' || second)::timestamp without time zone
```

Comment: And `timestamp` defaults to `timestamp without time zone`.