# Change the date format to dmy

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Can somebody tell me how to change the date data-type to accept dmy in PostgreSQL? These must be for always the default format!

Comment: Any reason you can't normalize to ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) in your client code? If you're not talking to your database in ISO 8601 formats then you're doing it wrong (IMO of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [**`datestyle`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting.

Also look at this recent, closely related answer:
[Integrate separate year, month, day, hour, minute and second columns as a single timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440492/integrate-separate-year-month-day-hour-minute-and-second-columns-as-a-single/13440802#13440802)